How to use imagettftext with umlauts?
The following php code produces correct results on Windows, but not on Linux.
I have no idea how to solve the problem, does anyone can give me a hint? The font is the standard Roboto font from google, which contains all required characters, as I can see under Windows.
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$total_width   = 500; // Breite Gesamtbild
$total_height  = 120; // Höhe Gesamtbild
$dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($total_width, $total_height);  // leeres Bild anlegen
$bg_color = imagecolorallocate($dst_img, 255, 255, 240);    // Hintergrundfarbe festlegen
$rand_color = imagecolorallocate($dst_img, 224, 123, 21);    // Randfarbe festlegen
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($dst_img, 1, 1, 1);        // Textfarbe festlegen
imagefill($dst_img, 0, 0, $bg_color);                       // Hintergrundfarbe malen
imagerectangle ($dst_img, 0, 0, $total_width-1, $total_height-1, $rand_color);  // Rand malen
imagerectangle ($dst_img, 1, 1, $total_width-2, $total_height-2, $rand_color);  // Rand malen (zweites Pixel)
$rp = realpath('');
$txtfont = "$rp/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf";
    
$txt1 = "Viele Gr&uuml;&szlig;e";
$txt2 = html_entity_decode($txt1, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$txt3 = "Viele Grüße";
imagettftext($dst_img, 12, 0, 15, 28, $text_color, $txtfont, $txt1);
imagettftext($dst_img, 12, 0, 15, 58, $text_color, $txtfont, $txt2);
imagettftext($dst_img, 12, 0, 15, 88, $text_color, $txtfont, $txt3);

imagejpeg($dst_img);  // Bild liefern
imagedestroy($dst_img); // Speicher freigeben
?>

Result on Windows:

Result on Linux:

Expexted was to see the same result on Linux as on Windows

Same version of PHP?

Windows is version 8.0.2 and Linux is version 7.2.34, but according to the docs this should not matter?

"Linux is version 7.2.34" - does that mean you're still using PHP 7.2? That is horribly outdated!

OK, I switched to 8.0.28 on Linux now, but the output is the same.

Is that actually the Roboto font? If yes, try getting a new copy for your Linux box, or copy the Windows .ttf over.

Yes it is the same font copied from the Windows box.  It is from [link] (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto)  Curious question: What happens when you run the code above on a Linux machine?

Just to see whether the problem is with the font or with the function imagettftext, I wrote a small test. It should produce the same table twice. On Windows, it works as expected, on Linux it does not.
This is the output on Windows:

This is the output on Linux:

And this is the test code:
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$total_width   = 860; // Breite Gesamtbild
$total_height  = 420; // Höhe Gesamtbild
$dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($total_width, $total_height);  // leeres Bild anlegen
$bg_color = imagecolorallocate($dst_img, 255, 255, 240);    // Hintergrundfarbe festlegen
$rand_color = imagecolorallocate($dst_img, 224, 123, 21);    // Randfarbe festlegen
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($dst_img, 1, 1, 1);        // Textfarbe festlegen
imagefill($dst_img, 0, 0, $bg_color);                       // Hintergrundfarbe malen
imagerectangle ($dst_img, 0, 0, $total_width-1, $total_height-1, $rand_color);  // Rand malen
imagerectangle ($dst_img, 1, 1, $total_width-2, $total_height-2, $rand_color);  // Rand malen (zweites Pixel)
$rp = realpath('');
$txtfont = "$rp/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf";

$li1 = 20;
$li2 = 440;
$ob = 20;
$abst = 24;
$format = '&#x%X%X;';
imagettftext($dst_img, 12, 0, $li1, 24, $text_color, $txtfont, 'chr()');
imagettftext($dst_img, 12, 0, $li2, 24, $text_color, $txtfont, 'numeric character references');
for ($i = 2; $i < 0x10; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < 16; $j++) {
         imagettftext($dst_img, 12, 0, $li1+$j*$abst, $ob+$i*$abst, $text_color, $txtfont, chr(16*$i + $j));
         $z = sprintf($format, $i, $j);
         imagettftext($dst_img, 12, 0, $li2+$j*$abst, $ob+$i*$abst, $text_color, $txtfont, $z);   
    }
}

imagejpeg($dst_img);  // Bild liefern
imagedestroy($dst_img); // Speicher freigeben
?>

As you can see in the Linux picture, there are 64 printable characters, which are only printed when using numeric character references. For 30 characters not printable with the chr() function (or with html_entity_decode()), php issues the following warning:

PHP Warning:  imagettftext(): any2eucjp(): invalid code in input string ...


After some more experiments, I know the problem is not the font.
On Windows all works as expected.
On the Linux of my provider, the problem is that imagettftext does not work with umlauts created by html_entity_decode. But it works with numeric character references.
So I wrote the following helper function for use as a replacement of html_entity_decode:
function html2ttf($s): string
{
    return str_replace(["&uuml;", "&szlig;", "&Auml;", "&auml;", "&Ouml;", "&ouml;", "&Uuml;", "&copy;", "&euro;"],
                       ['&#xFC;', '&#xDF;', '&#xC4;', '&#xE4;', '&#xD6;', '&#xF6;', '&#xDC;', '&#xA9;', '&#x20AC;'], $s);
}


What's the point in replacing ü with ü?

They are different (but the browser renders them the same way), just view the source code of this page.

Plese add all such explanation to your answer by editing it. Copying the code from your snippet to my IDE does not show any difference

@wuschel You can format source code with the Code Sample ({}) toolbar button. I've edited the answer for you.
